# Error al ingresar datos a un Datagridview en C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo un `DataGridView` que tiene dos funciones dependiendo si selecciona el botón `Agregar` o `Modificar`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el `DataGridView`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago `Click` al botón `Agregar`de la primera imagen sin haber seleccionado anteriormente el botón `Modificar`, si me deja pasar los datos del primer `DataGridView` al segundo `DataGridView`, caso contrario, si seleccione anteriormente el botón `Modificar` y posteriormente el botón `Agregar` me aparece el siguiente error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tiene el botón `Agregar` de la segunda imagen donde están los dos `DataGridView`(si se selecciona el botón `Agregar` de la primera imagen):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvInsumo.Rows)
                {

                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value))
                    {
                        bool exist = dgvInsumosAgregados.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row2 => row2.Cells["nombre"].Value == row.Cells[2].Value);

                        if (!exist)
                        {
                            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn filaTxb = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

                            DataGridViewRow fila = new DataGridViewRow();
                            fila.CreateCells(dgvInsumosAgregados);
                            fila.Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                            fila.Cells[1].Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                            fila.Cells[2].Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
                            fila.Cells[3].Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                            fila.Cells[4].Value = 0;
                            fila.Cells[5].Value = 0;
                            dgvInsumosAgregados.Rows.Add(fila);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Esta de mas decir que esta método no se conecta a `MySQL` ni ejecuta ningún `Procedimiento Almacenado` hasta que seleccione el botón Guardar.
Al modificar un platillo no me genera ningún problema solo al agregar.
Ya intente todo lo que esta mi alcance pero no pude conseguirlo espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Al parecer uno de tus DataGridView está vinculado a un DataSource ya sea en tiempo de diseño o de ejecución, busca por ese lado.

Comment: Hola, parece que estas agregando un valor mas, es decir: tienes diseñado el datagridview con 5 columnas y estas tratando de meter 6. Me parece que es eso.